# How to change Apple Watch priority to be over Fitness?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, fitness

When we start a exercise in Apple Watch and open another app, when we put the wrist down the watch will automatically switch to the fitness app.

It has some exceptions, for example, if you open the stopwatch and start a chronograph, when getting the wrist down it will keep the stopwatch in foreground.

But how do I set my app the "importance" to be over fitness (I'm developing a workout chronograph for my  own use)?

Everything is already working, just this part that is not.

The app is native for Apple Watch using SwiftUI.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/running_workout_sessions)?

Comment: Yes, @MrDeveloper, but I do not want to work with exercises directly. I have want to have my app over it.